# Cannot `Select DISTINCT`

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I´m trying to `Select DISTINCT` column in my mysql.

**PHP**

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT column1 as value, id FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE '%".$term."%'";;

$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
    $row['id']=(int)$row['id'];
    $row_set[] = $row;
}
```

The result will be the same as whithout using `DISTINCT`.
Why?

Comment: use group by column1 and some aggregate function on ID (group_concat, max, min etc.)

Comment: Remove `, id` from your SELECT clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `id` is unique (remove it to get `DISTINCT` column1 values):

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT column1 as `value` FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE '%".$term."%'";;
```

For example:

```
id column1
1 'a'
2 'a'
3 'b'
4 'c'
```

And you want:

```
column1
'a'
'b'
'c'
```

**EDIT:**

If you need `id` then your query works perfectly as expected. You can also try `GROUP_CONCAT` to get list of corresponding id.

```
SELECT column1 AS `value`, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids
FROM table 
WHERE column1 LIKE ...
GROUP BY column1
```

Output:

```
column1 ids
'a'     1,2
'b'     3
'c'     4
```

Comment: Yes, it´s unique and key. But what if i need the id to?

Comment: Ok, so my problem is that id will be DISTINCT... But how can i Select both column1 and id, but just distinct column1? I did try to wrap (column1) in. But with no effect

Comment: Thank you. I solved it by create an array key instead of the real id. (I needed the id as index). i guess your answear will be the best for this question.

Comment: @Mjukis so with sample provided lad2025 which `id` you want to get for the `'a'` key and why?

Comment: @alex I´m creating a list for Jquery plugin "Autocomplete". For this i need to have a key, for it to work properly. But i don´t really need the real id of the column, i can just create an id/key when i loop out the result. So, i removed the id from the query.